# How to remove a row in JTable via pressing on DELETE on the keyboard

Tags: java, jtable, keylistener

I know that I can use KeyListener to check if DELETE `(char) 127` is pressed or not, but how can I add keyListener to the selectedRow in JTable?

**EDIT:**

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
myTable.addKeyListener(this);
...
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.getKeyCode() == 127 && myTable.GetSelectedRow() != -1)
    {
        btnRemove.doClick(); // this will remove the selected row in JTable
    }
}
```

Comment: should be lowercase 'g' in `getSelectedRow()`. What does `btnRemove.doClick()` do?

Comment: @bemace I defined my own `GetSelectedRow()` method

Comment: well, *there's* yer problem. What was wrong with the stock one?

Comment: @bemace actually, I'm using a custom table so I had to define new `GetSelectedRow()` method

Comment: If you've got an entirely custom JTable using non-standard method names, the odds that the problem is in the 5 lines you've posted aren't very good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One issue with KeyListeners is that the component being listened to *must* have the focus. One way to get around this is to use Key Bindings.

e.g.,

```
  // assume JTable is named "table"
  int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
  InputMap inputMap = table.getInputMap(condition);
  ActionMap actionMap = table.getActionMap();

  // DELETE is a String constant that for me was defined as "Delete"
  inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), DELETE);
  actionMap.put(DELETE, new AbstractAction() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO: do deletion action here
     }
  });
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example for using Key Bindings?

Comment: @Eng: see above, but more importantly, see the Swing tutorials on this subject

Comment: +1, but I would use WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT. Not sure the exact difference but the default bindings either use this or WHEN_FOCUSED. See Key Bindings (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add one to the row. Just add one listener to the table and have it ask the table which row is selected.

You can also try `keyTyped` instead of `keyPressed`. Some platforms have had issues where one works and the other doesn't.

If you wanted to let users configure their key bindings you could as @hovercraft suggested and use key bindings. It requires mapping a `KeyStroke` to an action name with their `InputMap` and mapping the action names to `Action`s with their `ActionMap`.

```
table.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DELETE"),
                        "deleteRow");
table.getActionMap().put("deleteRow", yourAction);
```

Comment: actually myself, I'd use key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You add the `KeyListener` to the `JTable` as follows:

```
table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        considerDeletingSelectedRows(keyEvent, table);
    }
});

private void considerDeletingSelectedRows(KeyEvent keyEvent, JTable table)
{
    int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
    int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows();
    int selectedRowsCount = selectedRows.length;
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE && selectedRowsCount > 0)
    {
        // Perform actual row deletion
    }
}
```

For deleting selected rows, you may check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10136481/3764804) answer.