# How to make delete button to delete rows in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, listselectionlistener

I tried to make keystroke Delete but when I select cell and press delete button it enter in the selected cell instead to delete the whole row . How I can disable Delete button to do nothing when cell is selected?

---

noo. I have delete button on my GUI but I want to make keyboard shortcut to this button. I want to make delete button on my keyboard to call delete method. But when I press it when cell is selected it enter in the cell instead to delete the entire row

Comment: In ActionListener check if cell is selected and if it is just exit function.

Comment: Before posting a question make sure you have [thoroughly searched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for an answer and your question is different from those already posted on the forum. There are many related questions to your problem under the **Related** links to the right pane. Anyways, [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462842/how-to-remove-a-row-in-jtable-via-pressing-on-delete-on-the-keyboard) link seems to be more relevant to your query.

Answer (score 2):

The [`DefaultCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultCellEditor.html) for many [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) cell types delegates to a `JTextField`, which binds the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to the `delete-next` action. To preempt the default behavior, you'll have to remove the existing binding from `DefaultCellEditor`, as shown in [*How to Use Key Bindings: How to Make and Remove Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto). You can replace it with your own binding, as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513); a typical `DefaultCellEditor` is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10067560/230513).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:

 MyTableModel mymodel=(MyTableModel)table.getModel();
                int rowcount= mymodel.getRowCount();
                for(int i = 0;i<rowcount;i++){
                    mymodel.removeRow(0);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the automatic edition mode try this :

```
table.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE);
```