# How to use Delete button on the keyboard as shortcut for delete rows from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, shortcut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make delete button to delete rows in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236206/how-to-make-delete-button-to-delete-rows-in-jtable)

> Exact Duplicate to [How to make delete button to delete rows in JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236206/how-to-make-delete-button-to-delete-rows-in-jtable)

I want to use Delete button on the keyboard to delete rows from JTable. I have delete button on my GUI and only want shortcut. Also I made the keystroke but the problem is that when I select some row to delete in fact by default in the table delete button is used to enter in the current cell. I want to disable this shortcut and make delete button to delete the selected rows.

Comment: What prevents you from deleting selected rows in table?

Comment: SO isn't code generator, again for better helps sooner post an [SSCCE](http://example.com) , demonstrated described issue, possible duplicate with another users question

Comment: A general approach is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13240106/230513).

Comment: It's a question not to make a delete button/action/keystroke but how to actually do it may be by using events or smth.

Answer (score 6):

This is a relatively basic concept in Swing.

You need to take a look at [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Essentially...

```
InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "delete");
am.put("delete", new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionListener listener) {  
        deleteButton.doClick();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

There is no "default" action for delete on tables, so you can't disable it.  The main problem stems from `isCellEditable` on the table model and cell editor.  I typically have this set to return true under most circumstances.

While testing on my Mac, I found that it didn't use `VK_DELETE`, but used `VK_BACKSPACE` instead.

Once I set that up, it worked fine...

```
final MyTestTable table = new MyTestTable(new MyTableModel());
table.setShowGrid(true);
table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
table.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);

InputMap im = table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_FOCUSED);
ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();

Action deleteAction = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("I've being delete..." + table.getSelectedRow());
    }

};

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE, 0), "Delete");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE, 0), "Delete");
am.put("Delete", deleteAction);

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

**UPDATED**

Test on Mac OS 1.7.5, JDK 7, Windows 7, JDK 6 & 7 - works fine

Comment: I have made that but instead of delete row when i select some rows and press delete it enters in the last selected row. The question is how to disable already binded button delete.

Comment: No, that wasn't the question ;)