# Java Swing JTable (Table Cell Editor/Renderer Problem)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I can't find the reason why the problem is happening.

My program has 3 JTables, where buttons created as JLabel will invoke specific methods.

When I pass the TblBotao objects, the problem happens, but when they are instantiated in the JPanel constructor, the problem does not happen.

Could you help me and tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
public interface IClique {
    void clicar();
}

public class TblBotao extends JLabel {
    public TblBotao(String titulo, String icone, IClique clique) {

        setOpaque(false);
        setToolTipText(titulo);
        setIcon(new FlatSVGIcon(icone, 14, 14));
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                clique.clicar();
            }
        });

    }

}

//How objects are instantiated.
final var BOTOES = new TblBotao[] {
        new TblBotao("Editar", "img/icons/util/edit.svg", new IClique() {
            @Override
            public void clicar() {
                gerenciarCliente(TipoAcao.EDITAR);
            }
        }),
        new TblBotao("Apagar", "img/icons/util/delete.svg", new IClique() {
            @Override
            public void clicar() {
                gerenciarCliente(TipoAcao.APAGAR);
            }
        })
};

//Adding the buttons
int col = tblCliente.getColumnCount() - 1;

tblCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setCellRenderer(new TblCelulaRenderer(BOTOES));
tblCliente.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setCellEditor(new TblCelulaEditor(BOTOES));

public class TblPanel extends JPanel {

    public TblPanel(TblBotao[] botoes) {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));

        // This way there are problems.
        for (TblBotao botao : botoes) {
            add(botao);
        }

       // So there's no problem
       //add(new TblBotao("Editar", "img/icons/util/edit.svg", null));
       //add(new TblBotao("Apagar", "img/icons/util/delete.svg", null));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocusable() {
        return false;
    }

}


public class TblCelulaRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private final TblBotao[] botoes;
    public TblCelulaRenderer(TblBotao[] botoes) {
        this.botoes = botoes;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        TblPanel panel = new TblPanel(botoes);
        panel.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : c.getBackground());

        return panel;

    }
}

public class TblCelulaEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    private final TblBotao[] botoes;
    public TblCelulaEditor(TblBotao[] botoes) {
        super(new JTextField());
        this.botoes = botoes;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

        TblPanel panel = new TblPanel(botoes);
        panel.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        setClickCountToStart(1);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

See the behavior of the 2 forms, with and without the problem.

[image: with problem]

[image: no problem]

```java
// In the constructor of the TblPanel class, if it is 
// used this way, the problem with the first animation happens.

for (TblBotao botao : botoes) {
    add(botao);
}
```

```java
// Now if it is implemented this way, the problem does not happen, 
// and it works perfectly, as in the second animation.

add(new TblBotao("Editar", "img/icons/util/edit.svg", null));
add(new TblBotao("Apagar", "img/icons/util/delete.svg", null));
```

What is happening that when the cell is selected, the content disappears?
I couldn't understand, because when instantiated in the JPanel constructor, they work normally.

Comment: Honesty, start by making use of ActionListener and attach it to the button, instead of the MouseListener

Comment: I have my doubts over whether the `MouseListener` would work at all, as this isn't really how the editor is suppose to work

Comment: This is a personal thing, but I'm not a fan of having actions buttons per row, it seems very `80s web and has limited functionality ... do you really want your users to have to individually delete each row, over having the ability to select multiple rows and perform a single batch action, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070511/add-jbutton-to-each-row-of-a-jtable/25071138#25071138).  As for editing, why not just allow the user to double click the row or provide a popup menu (and include delete in that as well)?

Comment: You might even consider add key bindings ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13238585/how-to-use-delete-button-on-the-keyboard-as-shortcut-for-delete-rows-from-jtable/13239487#13239487)) which could lead you to making use `JToolbar`, `JMenu` or just some basic buttons along side things like popup menus to give the user multiple choices

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your suggestion for ActionListener is not possible because it is a JLabel and not a JButton.
 I have already developed others, where it was optional to delete more than one line, but now in this tool, deleting more than one line at the same time is not necessary, the edit button will be more useful, and another one that will be added in the future.

Comment: @MadProgrammer
I need to find out why the problem happens when JLabel objects are instantiated outside the constructor, and passed as an argument, but if instantiated in the constructor, the problem does not happen. What is wrong in the code to not accept the JLabel array.

Comment: I think, overall, your approach is wrong, as a "editor" is typically meant to provide a single editable element and the possibility is the `MouseListener` is probably not going to be notified when the editor is first "activated", which IMHO would be frustrating to the user

Comment: You should also consider providing a [mcve] which demonstrates your issue, as the time and effort required to replicate the issue is probably going to put many people off. *"Your suggestion for ActionListener is not possible because it is a JLabel and not a JButton"* which is just increasing my concern that this is the wrong approahc

Comment: Move `setClickCountToStart` to the editor constructor, not point calling this in the `getTableCellEditorComponent`, as the table will already be in edit mode

Comment: Okay, that took way more time then I'd really like - when using `for-loop` you adding shared labels to the panel, which are removed them from the previous parent first, where as the "other code" is creating brand new labels for that specific instance of the panel.  So rather then creating the labels and then passing them to the panel, pass the "configuration" information the panel needs in order to create the labels.  This is where the concept of `Action` would serve you better

Comment: You're also wasting time creating a new instance of the panel each time `getTableCellXxxComponent` is called, better to create the panel once and simply configure it as needed when called